# How to simulate material with borders in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am loading an OBJ element into my Three.js with OBJ Loader (http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_obj).

I changed the obj loader element to new `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({wireframe: true})`.
But now I have transparent element with wireframe:
[image]

What I would like to achieve (it doesn't have to be in such quality) is that I have solid face colors with borders:
[image]

Comment: Take a look at the demo http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_wireframe